# Select Where Multiple Columns do not Contain Value

Tags: sql, select

I have a table the has 3 email columns. There is a default email address (for simplicity we'll call it `name@example.com`) that we do not want to display. If the select statement encounters this as the first email, it uses the second, and so on. I only need the first email encountered that is not `name@example.com`. If all three are that address, the record is not returned.

As a quick test I tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM participant 
WHERE primaryEmail <> 'name@example.com' 
  AND secondaryEmail <> 'name@example.com' 
  AND ternaryEmail <> 'name@example.com'
```

This isn't good, because if the record entered was missing an email than `name@example.com` was inserted, so I **only** receive records that never contain that email.

**EDIT**

I need to specify that the only records the select statement would use are name and whatever email the query finds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `CASE`  in your `SELECT` to select the first non 'name@example.com' and changing your `WHERE` to use `OR` should solve your problem.

```
SELECT
    name, 
    CASE
        WHEN primaryEmail <> 'name@example.com' THEN primaryEmail
        WHEN secondaryEmail <> 'name@example.com' THEN secondaryEmail 
        ELSE ternaryEmail 
    END AS email
FROM participant 
WHERE 
    primaryEmail <> 'name@example.com' 
    OR secondaryEmail <> 'name@example.com' 
    OR ternaryEmail <> 'name@example.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try `OR` in your query instead of `AND`. That way you'd get entries where at least one email is valid.